# Program dumps data to stdout fast. Looking for way to write commands without getting flooded

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, gnu-screen

Program is dumping to stdout and while I try to type new commands I can't see what I'm writing because it gets thrown along with the output. Is there a shell that separates commands and outputs? Or can I use two shells where I can run commands on one and make it dump to the stdout of another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the program to another terminal window. For example:

```
program > /dev/pts/2 &
```

The style of terminal name may depend on how your system is organized.

Comment: This works best for me. The 'flooding' is like every second, not so fast I can't get use out of it, but just enough it's hard to write commands. I have upvoted all of you, wish I could give more points. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There's 'more' to let you pageinate through output, and 'tee' which lets you split a programs output, so it goes to both stdout and to a file.

```
$ yourapp | more    // show in page-sized chunks
$ yourapp | tee output.txt  // flood to stdout, but also save a copy in output.txt
```

and best of all

```
$ yourapp | tee output.txt | more   // pageinate + save copy
```

Comment: `less` is a better `more` IMO -- `alias more='less -e'`

Comment: True. On the Linux distros I've used, more's always been alias for less.

Answer (score 3):

Either redirect standard output and error when you run the program, so it doesn't bother you:

```
./myprog >myprog.out 2>&1
```

or, alternatively, run a different terminal to do your work in. That leaves your program free to output whatever it likes to its terminal without bothering you.

Having said that, I'd *still* capture the information from the program to a file in case you have to go back and look at it.

Comment: @Forever, it means send filehandle 2 (standard error) to the same place as filehandle 1 (standard output), a way of combining the streams.